# date copy stops the loop statement to function as intended

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, for-loop, if-statement

What i am trying to do is to display available rooms which are in **data**
i map the rooms using **data.map** , check if one is available between a given ( checkin and checkout date ) using **availdata[p.roomId][date].i==0** , if not it will display the available room .
the code works fine but as soon as it finds an available room it stops (which means it stops at the else statement ) and won't look for the rest of the rooms  .
Any suggestions ?
using **break ;** doesn't have anything to do with the problem i am facing .

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import HotelCards from './HotelCards';
import styles from '../styles/Options/Options.module.css';
import {Checkkout as checkkout}  from "./Hero";
import {Checkkin as checkkin}  from "./Hero";

import {format} from "date-fns";
let HC=[];
let prices =[];
let notavailableat="";
let rowss=[];
export default function Options({selectedGuest}) {
    const [availdata, setavailData] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isLoading2, setIsLoading2] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    // request Headers
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },

    };
    const requestOptions2 = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },

    };


    //Get the rooms info along with the ID
    const fetchData = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/rooms', requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())

            .then((result) =>{
                    console.log("roooms"+result)
                    setData(result.rooms)
                    setIsLoading2(true);

                }

            )
            .catch((err) => console.log("error"));
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    //get the i and p variables
    function fetchData1() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/availability', requestOptions2)
            .then(response => response.json())

            .then((result) =>{
                    setavailData(result.availability[0])


                    console.log('ooooooooooh'+result.availability[0][7264])
                    setIsLoading(true);


                }

            )
            .catch((err) => console.log("error"));
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData1();
    }, []);

    prices.length=0;
    var strToDatein = new Date(checkkin)
    var strToDateout = new Date(checkkout)
    let trys = 0;

    data.map((p) =>{

    if (isLoading && isLoading2 ){


        for (var day = strToDatein; day < strToDateout; day.setDate(day.getDate() + 1)) {
            HC.length=0;

            console.log(day + "dekhel for");

            var diplaydate = format(day,"dd  MMM ");

            var date = format(day, 'yyyyMMdd');

            if (availdata[p.roomId][date].i==0){

                rowss.push(<p key={availdata[p.roomId][date]}> not available at {diplaydate} </p>);
                notavailableat="not available at "+diplaydate;
                console.log(+p.roomId+"not available at "+diplaydate)


                break;
            }
            else
            {console.log("dateeee"+ date);
                rowss.length=0;
                prices.length=0;
                prices.push(availdata[p.roomId][date].p1);
                var total_price = 0;
                if(prices.length!==0){
                    for (var i=0;i<=prices.length-1;i++){
                        total_price+=parseFloat(prices[i]);
                    }

                }
                console.log("room:"+p.roomId+"price?"+availdata[p.roomId][date].p1)

                HC.push(<div key={p.roomId}>
                <HotelCards
                    idroom={p.roomId}
                    title={p.roomName.toUpperCase()}
                    status={true}
                    price={total_price}
                    img={p.pictures[0].url}
                    avail={1111}
                    rows={rowss}
                    guest={selectedGuest}
                /></div>)



            }}


    }

    })


    return (
        <div className={`${styles.containers}`}>
            {HC}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `.map` without `return` statement in the callback? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: i am displaying it as {HC} later in return statement .                                             
                                                                                                                                    return (
  <div className={`${styles.containers}`}>
   {HC}
  </div>
 );

Comment: There is no `return` statement in your code.

Comment: I just edited it , does this help ?

Comment: i didn't post the whole code as the problem does not remain there

Comment: That's what I mean. The `.map` doesn't make sense. You should use `.forEach`.

Comment: i know ! that's what i used first , they give the same result

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with actual and expected behavior? Currently, it's unclear what problem you have.

Comment: Okay , let's say i have 3 rooms ( one is not available for booking , and the two others are available ) , so the code checks the first room finds that it is not available ( so it won't be displayed ) and moves on to the second finds that it its available and displays it ) and then it stops without looking if the third room is available or not

Comment: Let's say you post a code, that I can copy and paste to run it and see and analyze the actual behavior. Ideally, you would remove the JSX code and post a JavaScript code.

Comment: the expected behaviour is that the two available rooms be displayed

Comment: i am preparing one

Comment: I've created a [mcve] of your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/f0hogd7c/

Comment: exactly but the availdata contains the rooms id like this [link]( https://pastebin.com/DbS2tFkx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is this assignment in the `for` loop:

```
var day = strToDatein;
```

Dates are objects and objects are not copied. The references are copied. `day` and `strToDatein` contain references to the same object. `day.setDate(day.getDate() + 1)` modifies `strToDatein`. After the first room was found, `strToDatein < strToDateout` returns `false` and the `for` loop is skipped for all other rooms.

You can fix your problem with a real copy of the `Date` object in the `for` loop:

```js
const data = [{
  roomId: 0,
  roomName: '0'
}, {
  roomId: 1,
  roomName: '1'
}, {
  roomId: 2,
  roomName: '2'
}];
const isLoading = true;
const isLoading2 = true;
const strToDatein = new Date(2022, 0, 1);
const strToDateout = new Date(2022, 0, 3);
const HC = [];
const availdata = [{
  "20220101": {
    i: 0,
    p1: 100
  }
}, {
  "20220101": {
    i: 2,
    p1: 100
  },
  "20220102": {
    i: 2,
    p1: 100
  },
  "20220103": {
    i: 2,
    p1: 100
  }
}, {
  "20220101": {
    i: 0,
    p1: 100
  }
}];
const rowss = [];
const prices = [];

function format(date) {
  return `${date.getFullYear()}${`${date.getMonth()+1}`.padStart(2, 0)}${`${date.getDate()}`.padStart(2, 0)}`;
}

data.forEach((p) => {
  if (isLoading && isLoading2) {
    for (var day = new Date(strToDatein); day < strToDateout; day.setDate(day.getDate() + 1)) {
      console.log(day + "dekhel for");
      var diplaydate = format(day, "dd  MMM ");
      var date = format(day, 'yyyyMMdd');
      if (availdata[p.roomId][date].i == 0) {
        rowss.push(`<p key = {
                availdata[p.roomId][date]
              }> not available at {
                diplaydate
              }</p>`);
        notavailableat = "not available at " + diplaydate;
        console.log(+p.roomId + "not available at " + diplaydate)
        break;
      } else {
        console.log("dateeee" + date);
        rowss.length = 0;
        prices.length = 0;
        prices.push(availdata[p.roomId][date].p1);
        var total_price = 0;
        if (prices.length !== 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i <= prices.length - 1; i++) {
            total_price += parseFloat(prices[i]);
          }
        }
        console.log("room:" + p.roomId + "price?" + availdata[p.roomId][date].p1)
        HC.push(`<div key={${p.roomId}}>` +
                '<HotelCards' +
                ` idroom={${p.roomId}}` +
                ` title={${p.roomName.toUpperCase()}}` +
                ` status={true}` +
                ` price={${total_price}}` +
                ' img={p.pictures[0].url}' +
                ' avail={1111}' +
                ' rows={rowss}' +
                ' guest={selectedGuest}' +
                '/></div>');
      }
    }
  }
});

console.log(HC);
```

Comment: I never expected this to be the problem , once i saw people downvoting the question i thought it is obvious . Thanks a lot

Comment: it is displaying only the last item in HC tho in render

Comment: @CharfeddineMohamedAli Please ask only one question per question and avoid follow up questions in comments. You asked about the problem with the rooms and this is the answer. You would find this problem and the other one with your debugger after creating and debugging a [mcve].

Comment: Sure thanks for taking the time to help me solve this.

Comment: @CharfeddineMohamedAli You're clearing `HC` on every loop iteration: `HC.length = 0;`. Why are you doing this? I've removed it and added a log of `HC`. You can see multiple entries.

Comment: Yes but that's not the issue , removing HC.length will result into displaying the same room displayed many times, i use it only to escape the re-render of useState

Comment: That's the issue. It's not possible to have multiple elements in `HC`. You're clearing `HC` at the beginning of the loop and adding one element at the end of the loop. It's not possible to have two elements in `HC` with your logic.

Comment: Yes that's true , will think of another way to solve this

Comment: but what i am trynna say is that i understand that i am clearing HC everytime  , but if don't do that it will display the two rooms in a correct way but it will also render them many times ( three of each of the rooms)

Comment: @CharfeddineMohamedAli Yes, the problem with programming is that the computers will exactly do what you tell them to do. If you don't know what you want, you can't write a code. You need a pencil and paper start making some decisions and writing algorithms and flow diagrams. Programming isn't only coding. It's much more.

Comment: problem solved , thanks for your help again